# Large MySQL Batch Query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a large array of id's and I want to iterate over each mysql record that matches the id.

I've tried various combinations of where, find_each and find_in_batches to no avail. I get the error: MySQL server has gone away, I assume because the where statement tries loading everything into memory.

```
# cust_ids is an array of customer ids    

UserObject.where(:customer_id => cust_ids).find_each(batch_size: 100) do |user|
  users.push(user)
```

Works for small files, for large files it yields: MySQL server has gone away

```
UserObject.find_each(:conditions => "customer_id in (#{cust_ids})") do |user|
 users.push(user)
```

Yields: Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :start, :batch_size (I believe conditions was deprecated, but I'm not seeing a replacement in functionality)

Comment: Is there an index on `user_object.customer_id`? If not, does creating one help?

Comment: Yes, there's an index on customer_id. How might I structure my query differently to take advantage of that?

Comment: Two more questions: 1. Is there an index on `user_object.id` (a primary key constraint is enough), 2. Could you post the output of `EXPLAIN` for the query submitted to the database? (You should be able to find the query in `log/development.log`; open `mysql`, prepend the query with `EXPLAIN` and run it).

Comment: Show Index from the UserObject table shows two indexed columns - id (primary) and customer_id. 

For a small file, the query in the log looked like this:
SELECT  `userobject`.* FROM `userobject ` WHERE `userobject`.`customer_id` IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', ...etc. )  ORDER BY `userobject `.`id` ASC LIMIT 100

For a large file no query appeared, instead this:
SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483, @@SESSION.sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
161228 23:

Running the first query with explain merely works, but it's too long to post.